# I can't find when apparmor start under sysV

Tags: services

I run a sysV linux distro: Devuan (which is a Debian with sysV instead of systemD)

I do:

```
/usr/sbin/service --status-all
   [ ? ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  bootlogd
 [ - ]  bootlogs
 [ - ]  bootmisc.sh
 [ + ]  brightness
 [ - ]  checkfs.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot.sh
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
[..]
```

as you can see, service apparmor is running right?

I check the default run level

```
/sbin/runlevel
N 2

ls /etc/rc2.d/S* -1
    /etc/rc2.d/S02bootlogs
/etc/rc2.d/S02lvm2-lvmpolld
/etc/rc2.d/S02pulseaudio-enable-autospawn
/etc/rc2.d/S02rsyslog
/etc/rc2.d/S02sudo
/etc/rc2.d/S03anacron
/etc/rc2.d/S03cron
/etc/rc2.d/S03dbus
/etc/rc2.d/S03hddtemp
/etc/rc2.d/S03rmnologin
/etc/rc2.d/S03rsync
/etc/rc2.d/S04bluetooth
/etc/rc2.d/S04elogind
/etc/rc2.d/S04network-manager
/etc/rc2.d/S04slim
/etc/rc2.d/S05rc.local
/etc/rc2.d/S05stop-bootlogd
```

apparmor does not appear
so I make a snippet to try to find if it starts at some point:

```
for i in {0..5};do find /etc/"rc${i}.d" -name 'S*' -exec basename {} \;;done | sort -u | grep appar
```

explanation: for i in {0..5} -> to check in all runlevel (except the 6th) ; I dont need the full path, so I basename, sort uniquely, and check if apparmor appears at some point but it does not spaw any output.

I dont know very well sysV, I certainly missed something, but I would like to understand what I missed.

Any idea folks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppArmor init script is linked in `/etc/rcS.d/`, to ensure that it starts as early as possible. You’ll find the script itself in `/etc/init.d/apparmor`, with an LSB header specifying when to start it:

```
# Default-Start: S
```